# How can I call an older version of a gem from the commandline?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Say I have two versions of a gem installed (somegem versions 0.10.6 and 0.10.5) and I want to run the earlier version from the commandline. Do I have to uninstall the newer version? Is there a way I can use a flag to specify which version I want to use? Something like...

```
somegem /path/to/dir --version 0.10.5
```

I checked the rubygems documentation, and it only describes how to use a specific version when you require a gem from a file, but nothing about how to do it from the commandline.

Comment: Why would you "load a gem" from the command line? Surely there's no point unless you're using the gem inside Ruby code (and then, you follow the instructions for requiring it from a file...)

Comment: I'm not trying to load, but simply run the binaries of a gem. Surely they are not the same thing. I need to have the run the older versions at times, or I'd like to run a gem I have modified, but also run the original gem when necessary. Since they are both named "somegem" Ruby can't tell the difference and uses the latest version's binary.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
somegem _0.10.5_ /path/to/dir
```

No link to documentation, because apparently there isn't any.

Comment: Do you reckon it's because the Rubygems folk are lax with documentation, or that this functionality is somewhat unsupported, or a mixture of the two?

Comment: This (actually, `ruby -S somegem _1.4.3_`, because `somegem` defaulted to running ruby1.9.1) worked for me with rubygems 1.8.15.

Comment: Apparently it is done in the install script, where the command being executed is actually wrapped to add this behavior https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/abf89e04954b8a2ddfb6948d0860111990a6efa2/lib/rubygems/installer.rb#L652 but I also could not find it documented anywhere

Comment: Actually, there is definite mention of this in the command reference.
https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install 

_For gems with executables ruby installs a wrapper file into the executable directory by default. This can be overridden with the –no-wrappers option. The wrapper allows you to choose among alternate gem versions using version._

_For example rake _0.7.3_ --version will run rake version 0.7.3 if a newer version is also installed._