# Execute specific version of a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I call an older version of a gem from the commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061596/how-can-i-call-an-older-version-of-a-gem-from-the-commandline)

If I have two versions of a gem, how do I choose which version to execute?

For example, if `gem list heckle` gives me

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

heckle (2.0.0.b1, 1.4.3)
```

and `heckle --version` from the command line gives me

```
heckle 2.0.0.b1
```

how can I tell it to run heckle 1.4.3 instead?

Would I need to use bundler in order to do that? If so, how much [yak shaving](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving) would be involved?

Comment: something like `require "heckle1.4.3"` might work

Answer (score -3):

You can easily do this with RubyGems.

For example:

```
require 'rubygems' # if RUBY_VERSION < 1.9
gem 'example', '1.2'
```

Further reading: 
http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4#page71

But using of Bundler is already a better solution.

Comment: I'm asking about running a gem from the command line.

Comment: Ok, and this you can do with Bundler - specify gem version wIn Gemfile and operate with `bundler exec whateveryouwant`.